# Unable to get Docker Registry to work locally, works remotely

Tags: linux, docker, debian, docker-registry

**Summary**

I've set up a registry container on a Debian host running on the default port 5000.

The Debian host runs as a virtual machine on top of a VMWare system. Port 5000 is open.

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name registry --restart=always registry:2
```

I then tagged an image for pushing to the registry

```
docker tag test-image localhost:5000/kp/testing:1.0.0
```

and tried pushing it

```
docker push localhost:5000/kp/testing:1.0.0
```

but it fails with `Get http://localhost:5000/v2/: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)`.

The output from the registry container comes up empty. As if the request never reaches it.

**What I tried**

I then tried to cURL the _catalog endpoint and it just gets stuck when receiving response headers, the connection itself seems to be successful.

```
curl -v http://localhost:5000/v2/_catalog
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> GET /v2/_catalog HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
>
```

I also tried creating a hostname for the registry on the host machine and setting that as the registry connection address but that ended in the same result.

In addition, I also tried adding the hostname to the `insecure-registries` array in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` but still ends with the same error.

I then tried setting it up with TLS using a self-signed certificate. Again, the connection seems to be established in cURL but no response headers are received.

**Works remotely**

Out of curiosity, I tried accessing it remotely so I cURL'ed the same address with the Debian host IP and it works!

```
curl -v http://<host-ip>:5000/v2/_catalog
*   Trying <host-ip>...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to <host-ip> (<host-ip>) port 5000 (#0)
> GET /v2/_catalog HTTP/1.1
> Host: <host-ip>:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Date: Tue, 09 Jan 2018 07:30:30 GMT
< Content-Length: 20
<
{"repositories":[]}
```

**To the question**

It seems really unrealistic for it to not work locally on Debian as I've set it up using localhost on both a MacOS and an Arch Linux machine. I don't think the VMWare system could be interfering with local connectivity, especially if it works remotely?

Have I missed something which is preventing the registry to be accessible locally?

Comment: Looks good to me?! The only thing I can think of is that you need to do this as 'sudo' on a debian based system. Just tried on a RaspberryPi (arm based registry image) but works fine the way you discribed...

Comment: @Ivonet sudo is probably the only thing that I didn't think of to try. Sadly running the registry under sudo results in the same error.

Comment: Looks right to me as well. Guessing something is up with the loopback driver, or maybe something with your VM. Only other thought is an IPv4 vs IPv6 issue, but your commands seem to be going to IPv4 so that seems unlikely.

Comment: for future readers - just try to reboot you machine. it's work for me

Answer (score 0):

isnt it need to have mount point `-v` for storing files in local directory  like:

`docker run -d -p 5000:5000 -v $HOME/registry:/var/lib/registry registry:2`

this way it uses the registry folder in your home directory at `/var/lib/registry` in the container, which is where the registry in the container will store files by default.

Comment: In theory it doesn't need a mount point for the registry. It would just mean that the images are only stored within the container and aren't persisted to the host filesystem. So if I were to remove the container, the images would be gone but that currently doesn't bother me. Though just to be sure, I also tried adding a volume mount and it resulted in the same error as I mentioned above.